# Highcharts- how to set yAxis to the closest or exact value in the series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/na74Lndg/1/

how can I avoid highcharts inserting the 12.5 yAxis line.

If the series has any data that goes 11 then I do want to see the 12.5 line but not if there is nothing there.

I have tried using softMax but that does not solve the issue,

```
yAxis: {
 softMax: 10
}
```

I sure can write code to calculate the max data series and set the max accordingly, but looking for an answer without writing to much code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `maxPadding` to `0` (or some other number that accomplishes your desired result).

```
yAxis: {
  maxPadding: 0,
  ...
}
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/na74Lndg/2/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.maxPadding

> maxPadding: Number
>   Since 1.2.0
>   Padding of the max value relative to the length of the axis. A padding of 0.05 will make a 100px axis 5px longer. This is useful when you don't want the highest data value to appear on the edge of the plot area. Defaults to 0.05.

You can also look at the `endOnTick` property, which would allow the axis to extend beyond 10, but not draw the next tick.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

Comment: Thanks this works. I did check the endOnTick, but I want the next tick to be drawn if the it exceeds 10.